# Django MYSQL created_date and mod_date with specific SQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I'm relatively new to Django, and am trying to have the following SQL statements for two fields that appear in all of my models:

```
sys_created_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
sys_mod_date datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

currently the model fields look like this:

```
sys_created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=False,null=False)
sys_mod_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

However, when I inspect the MYSQL database directly the fields look like this:

```
`sys_created_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
`sys_mod_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
```

What would be the best (most Django appropriate) way to alter these MYSQL columns so that the constraints listed above are contained directly within the MYSQL database? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think mysql cant save the date time  by default when object is saved. Its the django thing.

Comment: I'm almost positive that the SQL from the first snippet is valid for a MYSQL database (I know other non-Django systems that implement it for auto saving created and mod timestamps and datetimes). I'm just wondering how to override the default Django settings coming from the model fields. Currently, I'm running an alter.sql script that manually goes into the DB and alters the created and mod colums; but, I'd like to do it a more Django friendly way if possible. Thanks!